# I cant use wasd and arrow keys at the same time?

Tags: windows-7

I am having this promblem where if I press one key on either one of the arrow keys or wasd, I cant press that direction on the other one unless that key is the only key of wasd or the arrow keys being pressed at that time. For example:
I can press D and RIGHT, but if I do, I cant press W,A,S,LEFT,UP and DOWN.
If I press A and S then I cant press LEFT and Down.
Does anyone have a solution to that problem, cause I have searhed around, and found no similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could very well be a keyboard limitation.  Some keyboards use cheap controllers and can not register large number of keypresses and/or certain key combinations.

The very first thing to try would be to test with a different model and/or brand of keyboard.